# Cannot Deploy Rails App with Webpacker on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I have upgraded a Rails 5 app to Rails 6 and also migrated all JS files from the assets pipeline to Webpacker. In development everything works fine. However, when I push the code to production I get an error when I attempt a page load.

I am using heroku for production. The build process successfully completes.

Here is my error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. 
Possible causes:
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376725+00:00 app[web.2]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376728+00:00 app[web.2]: unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376730+00:00 app[web.2]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376732+00:00 app[web.2]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376734+00:00 app[web.2]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376736+00:00 app[web.2]: Your manifest contains:
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376739+00:00 app[web.2]: {
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376741+00:00 app[web.2]: }
2019-10-24T07:23:04.376742+00:00 app[web.2]: ):
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "manager",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "latest-version": "^5.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "qtip2": "^3.0.3",
    "scheduler": "^0.16.2",
    "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2"
  }
}
```

I'm completely lost. I've tried recompiling assets, changing webpacker `compile` to `true` for production. I've also tried running `yarn install --check-files` but everything runs successfully. I have also tried completely reinstalling webpacker with the following command: `bundle exec rake webpacker:install` then pushing the updated code to production but I still get the same error.

Here are my heroku build logs

```
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.01 KiB | 1.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.17.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.11.3
remote:        Resolving yarn version 1.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.19.1)...
remote:        Installed yarn 1.19.1
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
 remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v1.19.1
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
 remote:        info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning " > tempusdominus-bootstrap-4@5.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "moment-timezone@^0.5.11".
remote:        warning " > tempusdominus-bootstrap-4@5.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "tempusdominus-core@5.0.3".
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.9.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 27.57s.
 remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        yarn install v1.19.1
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
 remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning " > tempusdominus-bootstrap-4@5.1.2" has unmet peer 
dependency "moment-timezone@^0.5.11".
remote:        warning " > tempusdominus-bootstrap-4@5.1.2" has unmet peer 
dependency "tempusdominus-core@5.0.3".
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.9.0" has unmet peer 
dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" 
has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
remote:        Done in 5.14s.
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:  !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default- 
web-process-type
 remote: 
remote:  !     Unmet dependencies don't fail yarn install but may cause 
runtime issues
remote:        https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path 
vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of 
the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but 
the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To 
add those platforms to the bundle, run 'bundle lock --add-platform x86- 
mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java'.
remote:        Using rake 13.0.0
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
remote:        Using i18n 1.7.0
remote:        Using minitest 5.12.2
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using zeitwerk 2.2.0
remote:        Using activesupport 6.0.0
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.10.4
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using loofah 2.3.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Using actionview 6.0.0
remote:        Using rack 2.0.7
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using actionpack 6.0.0
remote:        Using nio4r 2.5.2
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.1
remote:        Using actioncable 6.0.0
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Using activejob 6.0.0
remote:        Using activemodel 6.0.0
remote:        Using activerecord 6.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.3
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using activestorage 6.0.0
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using actionmailbox 6.0.0
remote:        Using actionmailer 6.0.0
remote:        Using actiontext 6.0.0
remote:        Using public_suffix 4.0.1
remote:        Using addressable 2.7.0
remote:        Using encryptor 3.0.0
remote:        Using attr_encrypted 3.1.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 9.6.4
remote:        Using aws-eventstream 1.0.3
remote:        Using aws-partitions 1.222.0
remote:        Using aws-sigv4 1.1.0
remote:        Using jmespath 1.4.0
remote:        Using aws-sdk-core 3.68.1
remote:        Using aws-sdk-polly 1.26.0
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.13
remote:        Using msgpack 1.3.1
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.4.5
remote:        Using popper_js 1.14.5
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.11.1
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using sass 3.7.4
remote:        Using bootstrap 4.0.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Using thor 0.20.3
remote:        Using railties 6.0.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Using momentjs-rails 2.20.1
remote:        Using moment-timezone-rails 1.0.0
remote:        Using bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails 0.3.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Using mini_magick 4.9.5
remote:        Using ruby-vips 2.0.15
remote:        Using image_processing 1.9.3
remote:        Using carrierwave 2.0.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 5.0.0
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using responders 3.0.0
remote:        Using warden 1.2.8
remote:        Using devise 4.7.1
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using elasticsearch-api 7.3.0
remote:        Using multipart-post 2.1.1
remote:        Using faraday 0.17.0
remote:        Using elasticsearch-transport 7.3.0
remote:        Using elasticsearch 7.3.0
remote:        Using hashie 3.6.0
remote:        Using elasticsearch-model 7.0.0
remote:        Using elasticsearch-rails 7.0.0
remote:        Using excon 0.67.0
remote:        Using formatador 0.2.5
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2019.1009
remote:        Using mime-types 3.3
remote:        Using fog-core 2.1.2
remote:        Using fog-json 1.2.0
remote:        Using fog-xml 0.1.3
remote:        Using ipaddress 0.8.3
remote:        Using fog-aws 3.5.2
remote:        Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
remote:        Using fullcalendar-rails 3.9.0.0
remote:        Using hkdf 0.3.0
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.9.1
remote:        Using jwt 2.2.1
remote:        Using kaminari-core 1.1.1
remote:        Using kaminari-actionview 1.1.1
remote:        Using kaminari-activerecord 1.1.1
remote:        Using kaminari 1.1.1
remote:        Using libv8 7.3.492.27.1 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Using mini_racer 0.2.6
remote:        Using multi_xml 0.6.0
remote:        Using oauth 0.4.7
remote:        Using oauth2 1.4.2
remote:        Using pg 1.1.4
remote:        Using pr_geohash 1.0.0
remote:        Using puma 4.2.1
remote:        Using roxml 4.0.0
remote:        Using quickbooks-ruby 1.0.0
remote:        Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
remote:        Using sprockets 4.0.0
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using rails 6.0.0
remote:        Using rsolr 2.2.1
remote:        Using ruby_http_client 3.3.0
remote:        Using sassc 2.2.1
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Using sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Using sendgrid-ruby 6.0.0
remote:        Using stripe 5.7.0
remote:        Using sunspot 2.5.0
remote:        Using sunspot_rails 2.5.0
remote:        Using sunspot_solr 2.5.0
remote:        Using twilio-ruby 5.27.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.2.0
remote:        Using webpacker 4.0.7
remote:        Using webpush 1.0.0
remote:        Using wicked_pdf 1.4.0
remote:        Using wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.12.4
remote:        Bundle complete! 42 Gemfile dependencies, 135 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into './vendor/bundle'
remote:        Bundle completed (0.54s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of 
the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but 
the 
 dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add 
those platforms to the bundle, run 'bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 
x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java'.
remote:        Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        Detecting rails configuration failed
remote:        set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
remote: 
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        We detected that some binary dependencies required to
remote:        use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
remote:        present on this system.
remote:        
remote:        For more information please see:
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on- 
heroku
remote:        
remote: 
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        There is a more recent Ruby version available for you to use:
remote:        
remote:        2.5.7
remote:        
remote:        The latest version will include security and bug fixes, we always recommend
remote:        running the latest version of your minor release.
remote:        
remote:        Please upgrade your Ruby version.
remote:        
remote:        For all available Ruby versions see:
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote: 
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote: 
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 218M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v573
remote:        https://enigmatic-temple-38800.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.`
```

My best guess is that suggestion #4 is the problem `Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.` since the manifest shows as blank from the log but I am not sure how to troubleshoot this or fix it for that matter.

**UPDATE**

Please note that I am still using the Rails asset pipeline to serve css and images.

webpacker.yml (all default settings)

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for 
performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this log message `Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally` 
The problem is probably that you ran `assets:precompile` locally and then committed `public/assets` directory.

Run `git rm -rf public/assets` add the directory to `.gitignore` commit and push to heroku. Should work now.

Comment: I did try this but I already had my public folder in the .gitignore. Thanks, but still no luck.

Comment: Could you add webpacker.yml file to your question?

Comment: Ok thats looks exactly like my `wepacker.yml` think we can exclude this file from being the problem. Are you 100% sure that you don't have `public/assets` folder in your git repo? Maybe added it before you added folder to `.gitignore`

Comment: Somehow I had .gitignore configured incorrectly. I got it fixed with your solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Had this problem in production today... took me 5 hours to find this answer. Chris, your answer fixed it. I love you

Comment: Just tried this, but not working. `git push heroku
Everything up-to-date` which suggests to me nothing is changed. I'll keep at it. I reran `git rm -rf public/assets
fatal: pathspec 'public/assets' did not match any files`.

Comment: I fixed with @xuanchien comment in  github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2071. Doesn't make sense to me, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks similar to [issue #2071](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2071). In your `webpacker.yml`, under production add

```
extract_css: true
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your issue is similar to https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2071?

Comment: It is, and I have been through that entire thread but none of the suggestions there worked. Everything works fine in development, but pushing to production seems to break everything. I've tried adding binstubs, uninstalling packages and reinstalling, etc. Nothing works.

Comment: @CannonMoyer What ended up working for you ? I am going through the exact same issue! And I have tried everything

Comment: @NdaJunior If I remember correctly, I had a file added to the .gitignore that shouldn't have been added and it ultimately caused the issue. I cannot remember which file it was though.

Comment: @CannonMoyer Is there a possibility that it involves removing /public/packs from .gitignore ?